# Jetpack compose (Alpha 1.0.0) for production release

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-jetpack-compose

We have app in play store and being used by lot of customers. We are planning to redesign our existing app using Android Jetpack Compose. Is it allowed to publish to Play Store? if not, when we can expect it?

In general do you advice to jump into Jetpack Compose now or after the release of Jetpack Compose 1.0 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. According to `Jetpack compose Alpha` release blog they said that Jetpack compose yet not recommended for full production use. So i suggest you don't use yet for your production apps. Check and read the blog.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/announcing-jetpack-compose-alpha.html

> **Compose isn’t recommended for full production use yet, in particular as we work towards API stability and finish performance optimizations, but we’d love you to give it a try and share feedback. Join us in the discussion on the #compose channel at Kotlin Slack. Compose 1.0 is expected in 2021.**

Answer (score 0):

Compose is currently in beta. Now it has come in Release Preview Also. End of this Month July 2021, Jetpack Compose is going to be for production use. It is a revolution for Android Development.